# Flash Security help needed

Tags: actionscript-3

I am developing a player and i want to make it for only one domain usage for one download. If user needs again then again hew needs to download another version from my site. How can i make it. Please some one tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a key. a fancy hash of their domain name would do the trick, when a user downloads your app - they enter the domain name and receive a key. OR you can add it to your own databse and ensure your application checks the key everytime the player is run. That way you can see where the app is running from.

If they try to use the player on a domain that is not in your database, or the key does not work - the application can be killed.

So: domain name hash (maybe md5 twice), this is given to the user to add to a config OR you save it and the player talks to your server.

Comment: wow. thats nice idea. thanks man. Let me try it out. Hope this will solves my prob.

Comment: PM me if you need assistance - I could lend a helping hand if you need it.